problem with fill using grease pencil
I am new to the grease pencil tool in blender 4.2 LTS and am stymied when I attempt to fill gaps in line whilst  using the fill tool. I have consulted the manual and it is unclear what actions are needed to close the gap.The manual tells me how to identify the gap but is sadly lacking in actual methods to force this to close. I can see the visual aids that tell me that there is a gap there, however the blue lines do not cross and I am unable to find a way to alter them or manually close the 'gap'. I have tried various combinations of LMB with alt, shift and control but the expected fill does not appear. I am sure that this problem is just a setting in some dropdown somewhere but I have spent a few hours trying to resolve it without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Its alot easier for us to help if you can either  share your Blender project file or at the very least post some screenshots/GIFs of what is going on so we can understand what you're dealing with a little bit better. Stuff like this is harder to figure out with just text alone.  Instructions for sharing your project..

I tried a few other things after posting and found a workaround (sort of) . If I go into edit mode and edit the curve to join the ends using 'F; to close the curve, then, go back to the Draw mode and double click the LMB then the curve fills. Unfortunately I did this over my original test drawing so uploading it wouldn't be much use and I might have changed several things in the process. I could start from scratch and try to duplicate the error, which, I suspect, is due to me not taking into account end caps on strokes.  I am going to keep on trying.

Yeah, post some screenshots or share your blend file and we can help alot better.
